# Find research partner (profession and beginner)

Tags: graph-theory, graph-algorithms, approximation-algorithms, optimization, se.software-engineering

I've 10 years of industrial work, but in my free time, I do research, write papers to conferences, help to teach to my old friend at the university and I even did a Ph.D. full-time program.

Now, I've nobody to start to do researching with me and I prefer team than working alone. It sounds like a dating site. But my friend, trues me, I tried everything, but I had no chance to start it for a while.

Is there any "useful" page where I can find and build a team? I did it in the past I want to do it again. I want to do it for fun, so no salary, no boss, no fixed time (1 hour a week to all the time). And my main goal to write papers as much as possible, because I think this is the best and most professional way to share my ideas and result.

Area: Computer science, software engineering + field where it is applied: industrial automation, but I also used to do neurobiology research. But I'm open.

Update:

I don't understand the downvote. For example, I need somebody I can develop a simple, for example, user management tool (processing EEG....) for example on GitHub. I don't care if no one uses it. We can practice the team working, discover scientific results and publish them, get references, try the most modern technology (C++22, Git, Full-stack...). A lot of people are busy! But most of them have free time. But I don't know how to find them. Therefore I'm here. I hope you can help me find them, the community, the page... As I said they can be not educated (I've university teaching experience, non-English speakers,s or a professional industrial research group). Thank again! And please, dear downvoted, help me out what else I should do.

I read lots of silly websites useful for nothing!

Comment: I wrote several emails without any luck. They are not interested, busy, and suggested stupid pages. Can you imagine building a team using LinkedIn? I really doubt it, don't you? Or researchgate: everybody wants to finish their topic and their theses...
penpalworld.com or facebook.com is more useful for scientific activity. :-)

Comment: If you write papers to conferences why can't you network there instead of looking for webpages?

Comment: It is difficult for me to get a network. I go to "weak" conferences and everybody has different interests. And it was in the past, I need to restart again.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I don't know of such a page. Most researchers have specific problems that they are interested in working on, and would only want to collaborate on those. If you pick a particular area and focus on developing your expertise and interests in that area, you could potentially reach out to individual researchers working on the same problems as you. For example, I think they'd be happy to get an email about a follow-up on one of their own papers with contained a new insight or idea they haven't thought about. But they're probably less receptive to an email that's not specific to their research, or doesn't show promise (since it's hard to tell and collaboration is a big investment). In general, the earlier their career (e.g. PhD student), the more receptive they're likely to be. Not exactly what you asked, but I hope this helps.

Comment: Sometimes specific *(sub)areas* (or sub-sub-sub-areas) rather than specific *problems*, but I fully agree w/ the rest.